# Can a file be saved from the command line

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I’ve been looking into creating a makefile and one step I often screw up on is forgetting to save the source file from the text editor. Can this be done in the command line and therefore be automated by a makefile?

I’ve looked into solutions but most of them are vague as to whether they save them in the way the text editor does. Most other solutions are in relation to writing to the file from the command line with cat or other commands.

Comment: This depends entirely on what editor you're using, which you have not specified.  There's no universal command line tool that will work for all different editors, if that's what you're hoping for.  Note that most IDEs will have a facility to start the build (e.g., run `make`) from _within the editor_ and very often those commands will remind you to save your files first.  So maybe you should investigate that.

Comment: If you haven't saved the file there would be no changes and then eventually make won't run anything

Comment: Yes. But, nothing more can be said, because the question is to vague.

Comment: A proper text editor won’t let you exit until + unless you either save the file or confirm that you want to ditch your changes. That said, I’m not quite sure what you’re asking…

Comment: What editors are you talking about? Non-interactive editors like `ed`, or interactive editors like `vim`? Are you trying to edit a file as part of a Makefile recipe?

Comment: The editor I'm talking about is vscode, used purely as a text editor. What I want to do is have a line in the makefile that can automatically save a file that has not yet been saved in vscode, then do the normal make compilation tasks. This would just remove one step in the process of writing a script and compiling it.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "saving in vscode".  Do you mean ... "transform non-vscode into vscode" ... or ... do you mean "save currently open vscode editing session's buffer to disk file" ?

Comment: I mean the second.

Comment: And you want to do that from **outside of your editing session**, namely programmatically by a **non-associated** (*possibly third-party*) bash script ?